# How can I convert HL7 messages (from V2 to FHIR) using Google Data Fusion?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion, google-cloud-healthcare

I'm using GCP and I'm new to Healthcare.

I want to convert HL7 V2 messages to HL7 FHIR messages. The presentation says that I can do it using Google Data Fusion plugin:

> Accelerate your solution development on FHIR by importing your existing FHIR data into the Cloud Healthcare API from Cloud Storage. Transform your data from CSV/HL7v2 formats into FHIR format using Cloud Data Fusion plugins and manage it in the Cloud Healthcare API.

(*taken from [here](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare)*)

But there seems to be no concrete documentation on how to do that. Can someone point me to the right direction ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no public documentation available for that yet since the API is still on Alpha. To have access on this feature, you need to sign up in [Cloud Health Care API Trusted Tester Program](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/cloudhealthcareapiearlyaccessprogram/). Once approved, you will be granted access to the documentation and the feature will be added on your project.

I also for reference I found this [data fusion pipeline](https://www.devdays.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/Google-Cloud-FHIR-APIs-DevDays-2020-Virtual.pdf) on how to use the cloud healthcare plugins.